# В чем ошибка при создании Generic-метода

Tags: java

Собственно сам код:

```
public class Sort {

    public <T extends Number> List<T> sort(List<T> name){
        Collections.sort(name);
        return name;
    }
}
```

На выходе ошибка `no instance of type variable exist so that T conforms to Comparable<? super T>`.

Ок, редактируем:

```
public class Sort {

    public <T extends Comparable<? super Number>> List<T> sort(List<T> name){
        Collections.sort(name);
        return name;
    }
}
```

На выходе ошибка `no instance of type variable exist so that T conforms to Number`.

`T` расширяет обобщенный тип `Comparable<T>`, где `Comparable` - интерфейс. В методе, реализующем интерфейс определяются объекты, которые могут быть упорядочены. Следовательно, указание `Comparable` в качестве верхней границы **гарантирует**, что данный метод применим к объектам, которые можно сортировать.

`super` - устанавливаем нижнюю границу (исключительно). Зачем это? Что не так в коде?

**[Ответ] Реализация через создание класса:**

```
public class Sort <Number extends Comparable> {

    public void sort(List<Number> name){
    Collections.sort(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Number` не реализовывает интерфейс `Comparable`, поэтому вы не сможете отсортировать `List<Number>`

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, как реализовать это на примере?

Comment: реализовать что?

Comment: ваш `public class Sort <Number extends Comparable>` в "ответе" ничем не отличается от `public class Sort <T extends Comparable>` (только названием типа дженерика) и не имеет никакого отношения к классу `Number` (к тому же ещё и raw type используете). Что вам нужно сделать то?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если заглянуть в класс `Collections` и посмотреть на метод

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

то можно увидеть, что `T extends Comparable` нам говорит о том, что метод `sort()` принимает типы с интерфейсом наследованными от `Comparable`. `Number` не имплементирует этот интерфейс.

Набросал свою мысль про "написать свой класс, наследовать его от `Number` и реализовать интерфейс `Comparable`"

```
public class Demo {

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> sort(List<T> name){
        Collections.sort(name);
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<CustomNumber> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(new CustomNumber(3));
        numbers.add(new CustomNumber(2));
        numbers.add(new CustomNumber(1));
        numbers.add(new CustomNumber(7));
        numbers.add(new CustomNumber(4));

        List<?> finalList = sort(numbers);

        System.out.println(finalList);
    }
}

class CustomNumber extends Number implements Comparable {
    private int value;

    public CustomNumber(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return this.value - ((CustomNumber) o).value;
    }

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return 0; // без реализации
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return 0; // без реализации
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return 0; // без реализации
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если правильно я понимаю, то нужно, чтобы `Number` имплементировал интерфейс `Comparable`, так? Если верно, то как это реализовывается, не могу понять?

Comment: Да. Если хотите поиграться, то можно написать свой класс, наследовать его от `Number` и реализовать интерфейс `Comparable`

Comment: посмотрите, подредактировал топик, так верно будет?

Comment: Обновил ответ, то, о чем я сказал выше в комментарии делается примерно так. Вот так все работает и сортируется.

Comment: проще наверное свой компаратор указать, чем писать свой класс для числа

Comment: конечно проще =) просто решил показать как это плюс/минус реализуется в классах. @tym32167

Comment: а, ну тоже имеет смысл

Comment: @dmtr, а почему тогда аналогичный код не работал у меня, который в топике идет после слов `Ок, редактируем:`, только он реализован в отдельном классе?

Comment: @n199a ну вы объект какого класса пытались сортировать? если класс не имеет интерфейса компаратора с методом `compare`, то ничего и не выйдет.

Comment: @dmtr, класс не имеет, а метод имеет, тогда логично предположить, что метод должен выполнять сортировку.

Comment: ну так вы посмотрите на `Collections.sort`, какие дженерики там? Правильно, поэтому ваш вариант `<T extends Comparable<? super Number>>` будет конфликтовать с тем, что ожидается в `Collections.sort`, т.к. на вход должен приходить объект класса наследующего `Comparable` интерфейс